# How can I backup Installed firefox add-ons and restore

Tags: firefox, backup, plugins, add-on

I have downloaded and Installed several firefox add-ons and plugins. I like to be able to backup these add-ons, so that a new fresh installation does not require new Downloads.

So my question is --
**How can I backup my current installed firefox add-ons, to avoid redownloading?**

**Edit**
One answer Added a method to backup. How can i restore those add-ons without installing every add-ons I had installed ?. *(Like copying add-on files on specific directories.)*

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @Robert.Yes I also want to do this, there isn't any good enough answer. So How can I close them. _(I accepted an answer yesterday and planning to accept another today)_. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Unfortunately, StackExchange is set up so that in order to close a question, you ***must*** select an answer, or if there are no answers, delete the question. Just pick the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup Extension)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/). You can easily find it on the Add-on page of your Firefox: tools/add-ons

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can i restore them without reinstalling everything again?

Comment: Yes. It has a restore option. Read the features. I used it on Linux on migration and on Win XP-Win7 migration. Make sure you use it's back-up which will create a file from which you restore.

Comment: FEBE backed up xpi files, but no configs at all.

Answer (score 4):

Go to home directory and enable the option in Nautilus to show hidden files.(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)

You will see a folder called `.mozilla`, which you may back up to external media or copy to another location.

If you ever need to restore from this backup, just copy this directory back to the home folder under the same name. You may need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to see it, though.

Comment: Isn't `.mozilla` technically a directory?

Comment: yup sorry :) .mozilla directory. My bad

Comment: But I think it will also backup all the caches.

Comment: @AnwarShah Yes, but you may exclude that by not copying the Cache folder located at `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/Cache`, although that may be hard to achieve without using command-line `cp`.